# DataTable to Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a DataTable with 4 columns -

ParentDictionary, Id, Key and Value.

Currently I have following code -

```
var dict = t.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().
            GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("ParentId")).ToDictionary(
                    g => g.Key,
                    g => g.ToDictionary(row => row.Field<string>("Key"), row => row.Field<string>("Value"))
        );
```

Is anyone has solution to convert this table to

`Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>>`.

Comment: that's a heck of an object

Comment: Are you sure you have to have nested dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like that

```
var heckOfAnObject = dataTable
            .AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(m => m.Field<string>("ParentId"))
            .ToDictionary(
                a => a.Key,
                a => a.GroupBy(c => c.Field<string>("Id"))
                      .ToDictionary(
                          d => d.Key,
                          d => d.GroupBy(f => f.Field<string>("Key"))
                                .ToDictionary(
                                    g => g.Key,
                                    //you'll have to pick one of the value in the grouped values
                                    g => g.First().Field<string>("Value"))));
```

But the object is really complicated, and I don't understand why the last nested Dictionary is not a `Dictionary<string, IList<string>>`

And I wouldn't like to have to do maintenance on this kind of piece of code...